# Tool for creating .rar files on the Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, rar

Is there any good, free program for OS X that can create RAR files? Preferably with a GUI.

It seems there are [plenty of options](https://superuser.com/questions/52124/whats-a-good-way-to-extract-rar-files-on-the-mac) for *extracting* RAR files, but not that many for compressing them...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SimplyRar [(download)](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21430/simplyrar) will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, SimplyRar seems okay. I wasn't sure which answer to accept, but I guess this one, as Simplyrar is free (as in cost), has GUI, and you mentioned it first. :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Yosemite. I downloaded from MacUpdate (1.0.8) and the DMG wouldn't even open.

Answer (score 23):

You can use command line [rar for Mac OS X](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm), but it doesn't have GUI. On the other hand, it's useful for scripting. (I feel that it should be mentioned here anyway).

Comment: +1 for Terminal. But ... how do I install the downloaded files then to always be able to use the commands.

Comment: It can be installed through [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask) with: `brew cask install rar`

Answer (score 5):

Download [simplyrar](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/21430/simplyrar) it free and easy to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but [Rucksack](http://rucksackapp.com/) is a great app to create all kind of archives, ".rar" included.

Comment: Actually, Rucksack no longer supports creating 'rar's.

Answer (score 0):

[BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com/), it does rar's too, it's easy to use.
It does cost though.

Answer (score 0):

Install WinRAR into a [WineSkin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/) wrapper. Works perfectly.